# How to access args in a method passed in from template in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In the example below I am trying to call a method from the template and pass in some args.  How do I access those args from the method itself?

snippet from script

```
  methods: {
    showBinaries(job, id) {
      let test_url = process.env.VUE_APP_TEST_APP + "/api/v1/job=this.job&id=this.id"
      // how do i access job and build_id correctly here?
    }
  }
```

snippet from template

```
  <template v-for='job in new_jobs'>
    <span @click='showBinaries(job.name, job.id)'><li>job id is: {{ job.id }}</li></span>
    <ul v-if="showIosMasterBinaries===job.id">
      <li>test 1</li>
      <li>test 2</li>
    </ul>
  </template>
```

Comment: I think I am over confusing myself with the vuejs stuff.  Can I just do '/api/v1/job=' + job+'&id='+id

Comment: yes you can ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
methods: {
  showBinaries(job, id) {
    let test_url = process.env.VUE_APP_TEST_APP + `/api/v1/job=${job}&id=${id}`
  }
}
```

These are the same:

```js
const id = 1

console.log('this is your id: ' + id)
console.log(`this is your id: ${id}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as your `job` object has `name` and `id` properties, then yes you just pass it into the method from your template as you are doing. In the method, you can construct the URL like so:

```
showBinaries(job, id) {
    const test_url = `${process.env.VUE_APP_TEST_APP}/api/v1/job=${job}&id=${id}`;
}
```

You don't need to use `this.id` or `this.name` within the method since that would refer to a variable declared at the component level, like `new_jobs`. You have method parameters `job` and `id` which will have the values passed from the template.

Currently you aren't doing anything with `test_url` in the method, so you'll need to either use it in a request or set that to something that can be accessed outside of the method, but this should get you on the right track.